# SAS query - potential issue with spacing

Tags: sas

I am learning SAS and I don't understand whats wrong with my code. No error messages but when I look at the results, it cut off the 4th person and the numbers are wrong.

Code:

```
data sales;
input Name$ Sales_1-Sales_4;
Total=SUM(Sales_1-Sales_4);
DATALINES;
Greg 10 2 40 9
John 15 5 10 100
Lisa 50 10 15 50
Mark 20 9 5 20
;
RUN;
```

Comment: This is what the result looks like:

Greg 10 2 40 9 1
John 15 5 10 100 -85
Lisa . 15 50 . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only gave the SUM() function one value to sum, the difference between SALES_1 and SALES_4.

If you want SAS to treat SALES_1-SALES_4 as a variable list instead of a subtraction operation in that situation you need to include the OF keyword.

```
Total=SUM(of Sales_1-Sales_4);
```

You don't need the OF keyword in places like the INPUT statement because subtraction is not a possible meaning for a hyphen in that statement.

Note: I think that used to generate an error in the past since it makes no sense to call the SUM() function with only one variable since there is nothing to actually sum in that case.  But the current SAS version allows you to call the SUM() function with only one argument, so your code was syntactically correct, just logically wrong.

Comment: Cannot tell in a comment what you mean by name being cutoff.  So you mean the last observation is not created? Make sure the data is ended by a line that only has a semi-colon.  A RUN: statement is not needed since the code for the data step ends when the data lines start.